# MongoDB - Sort by the maxnium number of keywords in input

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am looking to build a mongo query that would sort the documents by the number of repeated keywords specified in the input array. My document looks like the following

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "invoice",
    "rules" : [ 
        {
            "_any" : [ 
                "invoice", 
                "invoices", 
                "total", 
                "order", 
                "bill"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Terms of Service",
    "rules" : [ 
        {
            "_any" : [ 
                "rule", 
                "rules", 
                "terms"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, say if my input array contains the following keywords

```
[ 'invoice',
  'invoice',
  'order',
  'bill',
  'bill',
  'bill',
  'bill',
  'bill',
  'terms'
 ]
```

Mongo should show the result for _id: 1 first and then  _id: 2 since the input array contains the maximum number of keywords that belongs to _id: 1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can put index in your arrays.
0: "invoice",
1: "bill",
2: "order",
3: "invoice"

Then it'll be easy with the array.length to put it in the correct order.